# Bootstrap Grid Fix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Evening to everyone.

I'm currently in the process of designing a very basic user dashboard. I'm using Bootstrap framework to make the process easier. I have used the GRID system throughout the project. Nothing complex. Just basic grids.

This is what I have done so far [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BidmW.png)

So you can see the problem. I have absolutely no ideas on how to get this one fixed. I'd like no WHITSPACES. You see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgbPa.png) I'd like them all to be connected even. Is it even possible to do what I want to?

I have tried messing around with the margins but then that will break the responsiveness of the website. Any ideas or suggestions are really appreciated.

```
    <div class="row no-pad">
   <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="tile" id="tile1">
         <div class="tiletit">
            <p class="titleend">First Tile</p>
         </div>
         <div class="tilebody">
            <img src="https://www.picgifs.com/avatars/avatars/alcohol/avatars-alcohol-093831.jpg" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
         </div>
         <br/>
         <h3 class="titleend text-center">Its your time <br> To have a drink!</h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm ml-auto">
      <div class="tile" id="tile2">
         <h2 class="text-center" id="datetime">Monday, 31</h2>
         <br/>
         <h2 class="text-center" id="datetimee">7: 30</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="tile" id="tile3">
         <div class="tiletit">
            <p class="titleend">First Tile</p>
         </div>
         <div class="tilebody">
            <img src="https://www.picgifs.com/avatars/avatars/alcohol/avatars-alcohol-093831.jpg" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
            <h3 class="titleend text-center">Time to <br> Make a &nbsp;<i>change</i></h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm ml-auto">
      <div class="tile" id="tile2">
         <h2 class="text-center" id="datetime">Monday, 31</h2>
         <br/>
         <h2 class="text-center" id="datetimee">7: 30</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So yeah that block of code generates the first row of tiles, I just use the same code all over again to get the second row

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code? So we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: Post along with your `css` to figure out your problem

Comment: @faisal97 there is nothing special about the CSS. Just a few background properties. Rest all is Default bootstrap. I haven't played around with CSS as of yet.

Comment: @Freakz0r  add other class with tile and put some height to that class.